# How Upgrade Git 1.8 to >=2

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have setup Git in VSC version 1.8.3 (Centos 7 box), since a couple of months whenever I open VSC I get a notification to update to a version greater than 2. I click on update, I get forwarded to an external url to download git. I understand that an extension should get updated by VSC. Can you please let me know the steps to follow to upgrade? Thanks

The exact notification is:

> You seem to have Git 1.8.3.1 installed. Code works best with Git >=3
>   Source : Git Extension     Manage   UPDATE    Dont show again

Clicking on "Manage Extension" VSC code displays details of the extension, what is strange is when I click on installed extensions, I don't see Git extension

Comment: The extension doesn't contain Git - you need to install and update Git separately.

Comment: How? I went through somne threads all indicated to add forge as repo but it seems it does not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

Install git, systemwide, from the official git website - or your OS’ built-in package manager: https://www.git-scm.com/

You can verify git by opening a new terminal window and just running `git --version`. If that’s up-to-date but VSC still reports you’re running an older version (after restarting VSC, for good measure) then check you don’t have another copy of `git` on your computer or in VSC’s `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Just found a working solution.
Git is installed by itself, it is not an extension. VSC is finding and using Git that is available on your system.

Solution from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/709433/install-a-newer-version-of-git-on-centos-7) worked for me(the second solution from the accepted answer):

```
sudo yum -y install  https://packages.endpointdev.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install git
```

I'm on CentOS 7